# Automation testing of mainframe application using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2

is it feasible to test mainframe, which is a desktop based application with selenium? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium allows to test any UI that can provide WebDriver implementation to interact with it.

If UI framework that runs your app provides a webdriver that can:

- associate the commands WebDriver implementations should implement with the particular actions on UI
- associate the way how the locators are built with the particular UI objects

then you can utilize that driver for your UI automation.

Comment: Indeed, would be nice to have a webdriver implementation to support it. But it would likely be limited in API coverage, such as open up terminal/command, SendKeys, and switch to window commands for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is **browser** automation tool.

It is commonly used to website test automation, but it is not limited to it.

Mainframe/desktop do not have HTML locators, which webdriver uses to locate webelements to be interacted with, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

To be practical... you can perform automation to some extent. but not recommended. You might consider winium which implements the JSON wire protocol to automate windows based application(with limited achievability).
I would suggest consider UFT with terminal emulator addin.